# Is there any way to show a progress bar during loop iteration in a rules?

Tags: rules

I have made a rule set and in my rules I load a collection of nodes into a list and by iterating, I perform some modifications in each node.

Sometimes the number of nodes is more than 500.

I want to know is there any solution in order to show a progress bar during loop processing ?(such as one when we update a module)

Comment: The update process uses something called batch.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used module called "rules_batch" located in "https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_batch". This gives me all things I want.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

At first I must appreciate Eyal who gave me key point .

I used module named "rules_batch" in https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_batch and it solved my problem.